# Random draw from a linear model

Tags: r, simulation, linear, random-generation

I'm building an individual-based model where one component includes increasing winter temperature over time (years). For each iteration of the model (say 1000 iterations that have 25 years each) I would like to pull a random temperature value for each year that comes from a linear model of temperature increase. So at each iteration, I would pull parameter values that incorporate their uncertainty. The individual-based model looks like this:

```
for (sim in seq_along(sims) {

**generate intercept and beta values for linear model of temperature increase**

    for (i in seq_along(years) {

**pull a value for each year based on the linear model generated above**

   }
}
```

Here are my parameter values from a summary of the linear model:

```
winInt <- -0.67 #intercept
winIntSD <- 0.56
winBeta <- 0.08 #beta 
winBetaSD <- 0.04
winSigma <- 1.29 #sigma
```

To incorporate parameter uncertainty, I'm doing the following inside the iteration loop:

```
int <- rnorm(1, winInt, winIntSD)
beta <- rnorm(1, winBeta, winBetaSD)
```

Then taking a random draw from the linear model in the years loop:

```
val = rnorm(1, int + beta*years[i], winterSigma)
```

I'm wondering whether that's an appropriate way to generate a random value from a linear model that incorporates uncertainty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly right, but you should account for the fact that the slope and intercept variation is generally correlated, i.e. $\{\beta_0, \beta_1\} \sim \textrm{MVN}(\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}, \hat {\boldsymbol \Sigma})$ where $\hat{\boldsymbol \beta} = \{ \hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1\}$ represents the slope and intercept estimates and

$$
\hat {\boldsymbol \Sigma} = \left( \begin{array}[cc]  a\sigma^2_0 & \sigma_{0,1} \\ \sigma_{0,1} &\sigma^2_1 \end{array} \right)
$$

is the variance-covariance matrix of the estimates.  In R, if `m` is a linear model (`lm`) fit,

```
betahat <- coef(m)
S <- vcov(m)
betasamp <- MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu=betahat, Sigma=S)
intsamp <- betasamp[1]; slopesamp <- betasamp[2]
```